# How to check if child category exist on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to check if a child category exist on Wordpress.

I have a Category Tree like this:

```
Category 1
  -> Category 2
    --> Category 3
Category 4
   -> Category 2
      --> Category 3
```

I wanna check if the category 3, child of category 2 and child of category 4 exists, but I don't know how to do it. Now i'm using term_exists like this:

```
$term = term_exists( 'Category 3', 'product_cat', 'Category 2' );
```

But term_exists recognice the Category 3 inside the main Category 1, and when i do the same for the category 3 inside the main category 2 returns that category exists because it cannot differentiate the parent category.

¿How can I do that?¿Can term_exists have 2 parents ID? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @josed you can use the wordpress function get_term_children.
It will merge all the IDs of the children terms into an array.
Then you can check whether the array is empty or not.
If not empty you can use foreach loop to extract the IDs.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/